# Disable all caching when implementing ICacheClient

Tags: caching, redis, memcached, servicestack

Good Morning,

We have a servicestack implementation that uses caching.

**We can swap between:**

- Redis
- Memcached
- In Memory

because they all implement ICacheClient. We change which cache is getting used by just changing a cache setting node in the web.config.

My question is, how do I go about switching a config setting to "Cache:None" for example.

I suppose I could have my own CacheClient that implements ICacheClient that actually does nothing but implement the ICacheClient interface but this feels hacky and dirty.

The reaason we want to be able to switch off caching is to just get a base line on performance for testing.

thanks
Russ

Answer (score 4):

You would have to register your own `NullCacheClient` since if there's no `ICacheClient` registered, ServiceStack defaults to using the in-memory MemoryCacheClient as a fallback.

Comment: Thanks @mythz do you mean that I should implement ICacheClient with my own cache class called NullCacheClient (or something similar) and if, for example, public T Get<T>(string key) is called I just return a null?

Comment: Yep, implement your own ICacheClient that just has empty impls and returns null.